# Color of the text cursor in an input field always takes black in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there any way to change the color of the text cursor for IE browsers? Other browsers handles it correctly using a reversible color.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the **caret** inside the input field (the little horizontal indicator that you get while typing), unfortunately there's no way to change it in IE.

On the other hand, if you mean the mouse cursor you get on hover, you can change it using the CSS `cursor` property;

```
input, textarea {
    cursor: pointer; /*makes the cursor a hand-like pointer*/
    cursor: crosshair; /*makes the cursor a crosshair*/
    cursor: url(img.gif); /*use img.gif as a cursor*/
}
```

More info about possible declarations can be found here: [little link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow IE is real killer.